# selet2 jquery library for Multiple select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, jquery-select2

i try to use selet2 jquery library (https://select2.github.io/) to get a Multiple select boxes but that is not working

```
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0-beta.3/css/select2.min.css" />
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0-beta.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { 
             $("#js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
        });
    </script> 

  <g:select class="js-example-basic-multiple" id="js-example-basic-multiple" name="tags" from="${tags}" optionValue="name" optionKey="id" multiple="true"/>
```

i don't know if i have to download something ?

thx

Comment: "Select2 is a **jQuery** based replacement for select boxes." Have you included jQuery?

Comment: i work on grails project it included automatically